# wxMenuItem accelerator specifications

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, hotkeys

I'm trying to use some numpad button (like `/`, `*` and digits) as accelerators for wxMenuItem (C++, GTK), but they doesn't works.

If I specify just `2`, only the ordinary `2` button will fire the event, not `2` on numpad with NumLock ON (while ASCII codes are the same).  It's the same with `/` and `*` buttons.

I've tried to find some specifications for accelerators in wxWidgets docs, but unfortunately they are not complete (for example, it says I need to specify `pgdn` for PageDown key, but actually both `PgDn` and `PageDown` works good) and give no idea of using NumPad buttons.

Tried something like `NumX` for NumPadX buttons - it doesn't works too.

**So, the questions are:**

1) Is there any **complete** specification for accelerators in wxWidgets?

2) If not, can anyone suggest me how to use NumPad buttons as accelerators?

Comment: keep in mind that wxWidgets is a cross-platform library. So "PageDown" may not work on some platforms. In regards to your fist question - does it work the same on Windows? Also what is you wxWidgets version? What is you GTK version it compiled against? What is your OS/OS  version? Finally, did you try the menu sample? You will need to modify the sample code to acquire the numeric keys as accelerators.

Comment: @Igor, the question talks about `2`, `/` or `*` keys... Even in case of cross platform, those keys are **always** present.  It's the case of a desktop calculator program.  Nobody is talking about some strange key like the ones you can fin in an Apple computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `WXK_NUMPAD2` (which is documented together with all the other [key codes](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.0/defs_8h.html#a41c4609211685cff198618963ec8f77d)) and the corresponding menu accelerator string (which is unfortunately not documented) is `KP_2`.

Comment: thanks! Other keys' accelerator strings are `KP_SUBTRACT`, `KP_ADD`, `KP_MULTIPLY`, `KP_DIVIDE`, `KP_ENTER` and `KP_DECIMAL` - just found them using triar-and-error way.

Comment: I've added the full list of supported strings to the documentation in [this commit](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/commit/7d9d5934b557df1f512e7eda93f350da68599450) now.